# os.chdir working once, then not working after called a second time; python script

Tags: python, linux, shell, python-3.x, ubuntu

in the following script, I try to clone all projects except two, then clone those two into homepath, not my projects dir:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys, subprocess, time, re

from my_scripting_library import *

bucket_hoss = BitbucketAPIHoss()

all_project_names = bucket_hoss.get_bitbucket_project_names()

print(all_project_names)

os.chdir(PROJECT_PATH)

print(PROJECT_PATH)

TOP_LEVEL_PROJECTS = ['scripts', 'my_documents']

for project in all_project_names:
    if project not in TOP_LEVEL_PROJECTS:
        clone_project(project=project)

os.chdir(HOMEPATH)

print (HOMEPATH)
print(os.getcwd())

for project in TOP_LEVEL_PROJECTS:
    clone_project(project=project)
```

output

```
cchilders:~/scripts [master]$ ./git_and_bitbucket/clone_all.py 
[u'autohelper', u'bookwormbuddy', u'buildyourownlisp_in_C', u'bytesized_python', u'craigslist', u'foodpro', u'govdict', u'javascript-practice', u'learn_c_the_hard_way', u'my_documents', u'neo4j_sandbox', u'notes_at_work', u'poker_program_demo', u'portfolio', u'scriptcity_demo', u'scripts', u'transmorg_django', u'writing']
/home/cchilders/projects
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/autohelper' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/bookwormbuddy' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/buildyourownlisp_in_C' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/bytesized_python' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/craigslist' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/foodpro' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/govdict' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/javascript-practice' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/learn_c_the_hard_way' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/neo4j_sandbox' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/notes_at_work' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/poker_program_demo' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/portfolio' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/scriptcity_demo' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/transmorg_django' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/writing' already exists and is not an empty directory.
/home/cchilders
/home/cchilders
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/scripts' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: destination path '/home/cchilders/projects/my_documents' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Since the script is now showing to be in the correct dir (my HOMEPATH), why do these projects still have a mind of their own to be cloned into the projects dir? Thank you

Comment: The script isn't showing the wrong dir for `os.getcwd`. You chdir to HOMEPATH (which changes the current working directory), and that's what it prints.

Comment: correct. Let me fix the question

Comment: Where is the code for ` clone_project`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is somewhere in your `clone_project` function.  My guess (since you didn't post that code) is that `projects` is either directly hard-coded, or is set to `PROJECT_PATH`.

Comment: haven't looked at clone_projects in several months, thank you

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, are you changing into a relative path and not changing back?

For example, if you start off in

```
 /home/myuser
```

and then chdir into project1

```
/home/myuser/project1
```

If you then try to chdir into project2

```
/home/myuser/project1/project2
```

You probably meant to chdir back to the starting point, first.